# How to Implement SmartReply just Like LinkedIn,Gmail, Google Allo in android programatically

Tags: android, python, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

After lots of research, find it out that it can be achieve by using TensorFlow SmartReply which will help to predict and give some response based on the input using machine language. But while integrating the same into my own android application, facing issue related to JNI libraries integration.It will be really helpful if someone has any sample or example code in this .
Followed the below link :- 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/e1ac119417e6301222c2847f5f82e8ff093d7552/tensorflow/contrib/lite/models/smartreply

Comment: There is a demo app in that directory: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/e1ac119417e6301222c2847f5f82e8ff093d7552/tensorflow/contrib/lite/models/smartreply/demo/app/src/main

Comment: @iga  I have tried the same but it fails because of some libraries are missing.Its not taking that libs, tried all the ways to make this code working  but failed .Have you worked on the same ?Are u able to make it working and running?

Comment: No, I have not. In this case, I would recommend to file a github issue with all the details of the problem.